# How to trim down paragraph using CSS?

Tags: javascript, css, bootstrap-4

I have long text. I need to just display first 4 lines and at the end of 4th line do triple dots and add text 'Read more ->'.

I tried specifying in CSS max height and `overflow: hidden`, it allows we to control how many lines will be shown. But I can't seem to do last line properly. I need to display 3 and a half rows, have dots at the end and enough space to put in text 'Read more'. How it can be done?

This is the layout I'm trying to achieve:
[image]

Comment: `text-overflow: ellipsis;`

Comment: If I won't have `nowrap` setting, it won't work. But I need several lines with place for 'Read more'